# "Identifier '__webpack_public_path__' is not in camel case camelcase" - eslint, webpack and worker-loader

Tags: webpack, eslint

I'm using webpack and I want to start using web workers. I had a problem with a path to web workers so I decided to use worker-loader.

This is my webpack setting

```
{
  test: /\.worker\.js$/,
  use: {
    loader: "worker-loader",
  }
}
```

I create a simple test-worker and I'm trying to import it. It works but I'm getting eslint error "Identifier '**webpack_public_path**' is not in camel case camelcase" which I don't know how to resolve. I want to keep camelcase setting, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I tried different ways to import web worker

```
import testWorker from "./test.worker.js";
```

testWorker is a function in test.worker.js file.
I also tried

```
import testWorker from "worker-loader!./test.worker";
```

Web worker works, I'm doing

```
const w = new testWorker();
w.onmessage = model.onWorkerDone.bind(event);
```

and it works, but I can't get rid of eslint error. Looks like something is wrong with the way I'm importing web worker, but I can't find out what.

EDIT: eslint:

```
"rules": {
    "camelcase": ["error", {
        "properties": "always"
    }]
}
```

EDIT2: eslint in webpack

```
rules:[{
  test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,{
  use: [{loader: "eslint-loader",
  options: {
    quiet: true
  }
 }]
}]
```

Comment: is your eslint part of your build too? it is a pre loader?

Comment: It's part of the build.

Comment: can you post it too?

Comment: I added camelcase rule part, I assume that's what you are interested to see.

Comment: I meant the whole section that eslint is being added to your build process, not just the rules.

Comment: I'm using eslint 5.0.1 if that matters.